# Why doesn't git merge changes when two branches are different but with no new commits in either branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

For example,

I my master branch has stuff in it. Another branch called `other_branch` has stuff+more_stuff in it. Each branch has nothing to commit.

If I checkout master then try to merge other_branch, git says "Already up-to-date." and nothing happend. why won't more_stuff be merged into master in this case? Is that how git was designed?

NOTE: other_branch was created from an older commit of master.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very simple. If git says "Already up-to-date" it means the branches have not diverged. Two branches have diverged if at least one of the branches contains a commit that the other branch doesn't have.

I'm not sure what you mean by has stuff + more_stuff in it. If you have added new files to other_branch (or changed existing files), and used "git add" and "git commit" other_branch history will have diverged from the master branch. Since git says that there are no changes to merge, the history hasn't changed on that branch, i.e. you haven't committed anything.

Comment: Oh, I get it. It's not very apparent to a beginner. other_branch contains the same commits as master because I initiated it from an older commit of master. I was confused because when I checkout other_branch, I see different files, so I thought git merge would merge the files into master. I understand how it works now. git merge is based on the commits, not the current work tree.

Answer (score 2):

It only happens when the the branch you are trying to merge is already contained in the current branch.

So, the `more_stuff` you mentioned is already in the master branch.

You can use `gitk` to check the visual tree of your branches.

Comment: gitk? not sure what that is

Comment: It's the default git GUI. [More info here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)